# Populating checkbox;s with the result of an Ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have a form which opens for editing. The form is populated from the results of an Ajax call.
The form has six checkbox's which I am trying to populate as "checked" or "unchecked".

The checkbox;s:

```
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day0" id="Day0" value="0">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day1" id="Day1" value="1">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day2" id="Day2" value="2">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day3" id="Day3" value="3">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day4" id="Day4" value="4">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day5" id="Day5" value="5">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day6" id="Day6" value="6">
<input class="all" type="checkbox" name="Everyday" id="Everyday">
```

What I require is if the result of "result[20]" is 0 (this is a day number) to make the checkbox ticked (true) and so on for all the checkbos's

The result of the Ajax call is:

```
var day0 = result[20];
if(day0 == '0'){
   $('#Day0').prop('checked', true);
} else {
    $('#Day0').prop('checked', false);
}

var day1 = result[21];
if(day1 == '1'){
   $('#Day1').prop('checked', true);
} else {
   $('#Day1').prop('checked', false);
}

// and so on
```

Many thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: @Taplar my mistake. I have edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the array, using the index.  The if else can be condensed as well.  Slicing the array at element 20, lets the index start at 0.

```js
var result = ["11","April","DS1","Lobby","L","test_1920x1080.png","PNG","01-04-2019","00","00","30-04-2019","23","59","1920","1080","EXBHX","642652","6000","fade","600","","1","","3","","5",""];

result.slice(20).forEach(function(day, index) {
  $('#Day' + index).prop('checked', day && day == index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day0" id="Day0" value="0">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day1" id="Day1" value="1">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day2" id="Day2" value="2">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day3" id="Day3" value="3">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day4" id="Day4" value="4">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day5" id="Day5" value="5">
<input class="days" type="checkbox" name="day6" id="Day6" value="6">
```

Comment: hi, still not populating the checkbox's and I am not getting any errors in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: Modified the answer to be a runnable, after fixing one logic issue, so it should work now.

Comment: Hi, sorry to be a pain but I am still having issues. Can you explain why my array won't work. My Array: var result = ["11","April","DS1","Lobby","L","test_1920x1080.png","PNG","01-04-2019","00","00","30-04-2019","23","59","1920","1080","EXBHX","642652","6000","fade","600","","1","","3","","5",""]

Comment: @DCJones edited the snippet to use your array.  It still works in the snippet. Edit: Actually had to modify it as the value of the array was not 20, 21, 22, etc, but 1, 3, 5